# IOS what is the view with image at the top and table view at the rest

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a small application for basketball teams.

Each team has a logo and a list of players.

I want to build a view controller for each team.

What is the best practice for that considering the logo and the table view?

#### What I have thought

I've thought that I should use a `UITableViewControler`, but I wouldn't be able to insert the image. In other words, I could insert it at the first cell but I don't thing it is the best practice.

#### Edit

I also thought to use a tableView with two cell identifiers.

Could you help me please?

I appreciate your time and efforts.

Regards,

Comment: UITableViews have a tableHeaderView and a tableFooterView. You could use the tableHeaderView to show your logo.

Comment: Dear @CrimsonChris, Really? I didn't know that. Thank you very much. I will start learning about it. Please write an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UITableView` has a `tableHeaderView` and a `tableFooterView`. These are displayed above and below your table respectively. They are not to be confused with section headers and footers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Dear, Many thanks. I will accept your answer when the system allows.

Answer (score 0):

Chris' answer is probably the best answer for this case because all you need is a view at the top of your table view. If you needed something more complex, you could create a regular UITableViewController, add a container view to it, and control-drag from the container view to a UITableViewController scene in your storyboard. This would creat an "embed segue", and turn the table view controller into a child view controller. that would let you do things like place more than one UITableViewController on a window, add multiple buttons/labels on the top/sides, or whatever.

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your answer, I tried it but I had this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930518/ios-adding-label-to-tableview-header-removes-the-image Could you check please?