# IOS adding label to tableview header removes the image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a header to my UITableViewController. I am trying to do that from storyboard not from code.

I tried to drag and ImageView to the top of the TableView and drop it. Then, it becomes the header. I wanted to add a label next to that image but I couldn't for two reasons.

The first reason is that the image can't be resize vertically. it just can be resize horizantally. The second one is when I drag the label, the image disappear completely,

#### When adding image

[image]

When adding the label

please notice that the image at the left is gone.
[image]

I appreciate your help and efforts.

The required View

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a single view as a table view header.

To get around this you can add a ui view as the "single" view and then add stuff to it as sub views.

First add a `UIView`.

Then add a `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to that view.

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your answer, Do you mean to do that in the storyboard or in the code? I would prefer storyboard.

Comment: @CarolSmith Yeah, you can only have one view as the table header view. So first off, add just a plain `UIView` in the storyboard. Then drag a UIImageView onto that view. It will then become a subview of the UIView... and same with a UILabel.

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your comment. Actually there is no `UIView`. However, there are `View` and `Container View`, which one should I use please?

Comment: @CarolSmith View is a `UIView`. Tap on it and the description will pop up to tell you that :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AhmadDwaik'Warlock' I disagree. The OP wanted to add a label and a uiimageview as a table view header. This is how to add them both. You can't really create much more of an answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister you need to add more explaination

Comment: @AhmadDwaik'Warlock' ok, added a couple of sentences. Doesn't really change the answer though :)

Comment: Dear @Fogmeister, I am afraid to use a different view that is why I edited the question and added an image. Kindly check.

Comment: Dear @AhmadDwaik'Warlock', Thanks for your comments. To be honest, This answer is what I was looking for. Regards.

Comment: @CarolSmith all it is is a place to put other views. There is no reason not to use it. The thing you have circled in red. Just drag it onto the tableview header area. Then you will be able to add a label and an image view to that.

Comment: Dear @Fogmeister, Yes I did that and It works with me. I appreciate your time and efforts with me. +1